# Write NSMutableArray to txt file

Tags: objective-c

I have an `NSMutableArray` of `NSStrings`, which I want to write to a text file, so that each string has its own line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Guys, please at least take some time to write a proper title and question if you expect others to spend theirs helping you out. On a related note there's a shift key at your service: It's `NSMutableArray` not `Nsmutablearray`, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a full string of your `NSMutableArray` with

```
- (NSString *)componentsJoinedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

Something like

```
NSString* fullString = [yourArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

You can then use

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

on the `fullString` to write it on disk.

Comment: may I ask it give me warning that writetofile:tomically is deprecated any suggestion

Comment: Exactly `writeToFile:atomically:` is deprecated. You need to use the method I posted in the original answer : `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`